# Fatal error: Call to a member function pg_fetch_object()

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new in PHP, I want to show one column of my table called music,
the table name is a composer,
but every time I give an error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function pg_fetch_object() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/music.php on line 35

here is my code:

```
<?php

$host ="localhost";  //host
$username="root"; //username
$password ="";//password of the database
$dbName="wikiseda";//database Name
$tbl_name="users";
$tbl_music="music";
//______________________________
$connection=mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password") or die("can't connect sorry");
mysql_select_db($dbName,$connection) or die('can not select db');

$sql ="SELECT * FROM music";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = $result-> pg_fetch_object()){
        $musicname = $row->composer;
        echo "$musicname";
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `pg_fetch_object` to `mysql_fetch_object`

Comment: thanks but not solved! , here is a new error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function mysql_fetch_object() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/music.php on line 35

Comment: i change my code to : ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) and now that's work, thanks to help

Comment: what difference between "pg_fetch_object" and mysql_fetch_object ?

Answer (score 1):

1. mysql_fetch_object returns object as result.
2. mysql_fetch_row returns array as result

try

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
        $musicname = $row->composer;
        echo "$musicname";
        }
```

Comment: thanks but your code not work, i change my code to: ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) and now that's work,thanks again

Comment: great @Radian. I have just missed to pass $result.